# Google Analytics - Track Multiple Subdirectories (regex)

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to create a view in Google Analytics to filter out the analytics from multiple subdirectories and all pages in them.

- www.example.com/mysite
- www.example.com/anothersite
- www.example.com/lastsite

This is the regex I have written but when I run it, no results get returned `^/(mysite|anothersite|lastsite)?/*`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution by first adding a trailing slash to the URLs (see: https://www.getelevar.com/how-to/fix-duplicate-url-google-analytics/) and then including a regex pattern of the request URI of `^/(mysite|anothersite|lastsite)/`